# Rails using Symbol vs String as key in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

If we use a string as a Hash key, Ruby needs to evaluate the string and look at it's contents (and compute a hash function on that) and compare the result against the (hashed) values of the keys which are already stored in the Hash.

If we use a symbol as a Hash key, it's implicit that it's immutable, so Ruby can basically just do a comparison of the (hash function of the) object-id against the (hashed) object-ids of keys which are already stored in the Hash. (much faster).

But the thing is in Rails `params` which is instance of `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, if we write `params[:some_key]` it converts `:some_key` to `'some_key'` and then it tries to look for the key in params hash.
 [line 159](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/808592bae2b83ced018f16d576d41a0059ed302a/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb#L159)

```
 def convert_key(key)
    key.kind_of?(Symbol) ? key.to_s : key
  end
```

so if the lookup is slow with String as key in Hash, why does `HashWithIndifferentAccess` converts symbol key to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason used to be security. It's no longer relevant in Ruby 2.2 or later.

Before Ruby 2.2 symbols were not garbage collected. This means that once a symbol was created via a literal (`:my_symbol`) or `#to_sym` it would be around *forever*.

If Rails used symbols instead of strings then it would create symbols corresponding to names of params in a request. An attacker could send requests with params named `param1`, `param2`, ... and exhaust server memory by making the app allocate hundreds of thousands of symbols.

It's no longer the case in Ruby 2.2 or later

Comment: Ok got it now, Thanks for this !!

Answer (score 0):

`:symbol.to_s` will always create a new instance string, whereas, `"string".to_sym` will always produce same symbol.

```
p "string".to_sym.object_id
#=> 272028
p "string".to_sym.object_id
#=> 272028

p :symbol.to_sym.to_s.object_id
#=>70127441809260
p :symbol.to_sym.to_s.object_id
#=>70127441809160
```

Hence, it seems that designers of the class store the keys as strings to avoid unnecessary creation of strings during access, especially if one is using `hash.keys` method (it returns keys as strings).

Answer (score 0):

In case of integer key, HashWithIndeffrentAccess returns nil, so it's safe to use String

```
pry(main)> hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
#=> {}
[2] pry(main)> hash[1] = "a"
#=> "a"
[3] pry(main)> hash
#=> {1=>"a"}
[4] pry(main)> hash["1"]
#=> nil
```

Also we can not use integers like this

```
 pry(main)> hash[:1] = "a"
 SyntaxError: unexpected integer literal, expecting literal content or terminator or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR
```